# Hudson cannot find cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, hudson

I have a problem to bluid my C++ project with Hudson and cmake. I use a slave machine to build my project and i have the error message.

```
MODULE: C:/Users/abenchaaben/Documents/Full/JCLib
Build   dir  : C:/Users/abenchaaben/Documents/Full/JCLib/cpp
Source  dir  : C:/Users/abenchaaben/Documents/Full/JCLib/cpp
Install dir  : 
[deploy_test] $ C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin -version
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: Cannot run program "C:\Program" (in directory "C:\Users\abenchaaben\Documents\deploy_test"): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program" (in directory "C:\Users\abenchaaben\Documents\deploy_test"): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to escape the string containing the path to the cmake executable. It tries to run C:\Program and treats the rest of the string as parameters.